# Combining Tables in dplyr

Tags: r

I have a large data set, and I'm trying to create a table that shows the number of observations in each zip code for each year. The tricky part is I need each column to be a year, and the rows to be the number of observations of each zip code in each year. Some zip codes have no observations in one of the years, so there should be some empty slots. I only know how to create three separate tables with the three separate years, which is what the code is for below. Could someone help me basically combine this into one table?

```
BuildingZipCodes18 <- Data %>% 
  filter(year(`Issued Date`) == 2018) %>%
  group_by(`Zip`) %>%
  summarise("2018" = n())

BuildingZipCodes19 <- Data %>% 
  filter(year(`Issued Date`) == 2019) %>%
  group_by(`Zip`) %>%
  summarise("2019" = n())


 BuildingZipCodes20 <- Data %>% 
  filter(year(`Issued Date`) == 2020) %>%
  group_by(`Zip`) %>%
  summarise("2020" = n())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of filtering data for each year try using `count` which will give you number of rows for each `Zip` code in each year.

```
library(dplyr)
result <- Data %>% count(Zip, year = lubridate::year(`Issued Date`))
```

In base R you could use `table` :

```
table(Data$Zip, format(Data$`Issued Date`, '%Y'))
```

Comment: Thank you! The table function printed how I wanted, with each year as a column. However, it prints in a different style. It shows up in the environment as a value instead of data. Is there anyway to get the results of table() to be a data table I can view like count() did.

Comment: @Ben You can do `result <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(Data$Zip, format(Data$\`Issued Date\`, '%Y')))`